# React appends <Link to=""></Link> url to the present path of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The present path of my component is http://localhost:3000/dashboard/questionnaire/5bf79ff4c45a150015cef7a9 inside this component there is

```
<Link to={`dashboard/financials/${businessId}`}>Financials</Link>
```

If the url is clicked on, it redirects to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/questionnaire/dashboard/financials/5bf79ff4c45a150015cef7a9 instead of http://localhost:3000/dashboard/financials/5bf79ff4c45a150015cef7a9

Comment: For all the noobs like me. If you are using external links use <a> tag instead of <Link>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you are declaring relative path in your `Link` component, it appends your `path` to the end of the current location.

In order to replace whole path just use absolute path putting `/` before url.

`` <Link to={`/dashboard/financials/${businessId}`}>Financials</Link> ``

Comment: I had the same problem. When I add the / and hover over the URL it shows the right thing but when I click on it the URL changes and the page does not render